# How to select a subset of pandas DateTimeIndex whose data are in a list?

Tags: python, pandas

Lets say I have a `idx=pd.DatatimeIndex` with one minute frequency. I also have a list of bad dates (each are of type `pd.Timestamp` without the time information) that I want to remove from the original `idx`. How do I do that in pandas?

Comment: Please provide some sample data

Comment: not only sample data, but the expected output, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`normalize`** to remove the time part from your index so you can do a simple `~` + `isin` selection, i.e. find the dates **not in** that bad list.  You can further ensure your list of dates don't have a time part with the same `[x.normalize() for x in bad_dates]` if you need to be extra safe.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(range(9), index=pd.date_range('2010-01-01', freq='11H', periods=9))
bad_dates = [pd.Timestamp('2010-01-02'), pd.Timestamp('2010-01-03')]
```

#### Code

```
df[~df.index.normalize().isin(bad_dates)]

#                     0
#2010-01-01 00:00:00  0
#2010-01-01 11:00:00  1
#2010-01-01 22:00:00  2
#2010-01-04 05:00:00  7
#2010-01-04 16:00:00  8
```