# Python slice Dataframe rows based on the another dataframe index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have master and slave dataframe. I want to slice Master df rows based on the index of slave df.

```
mdf = 
                           A
2020-03-09 14:07:00    95.469030  
2020-03-09 14:08:00    -5.434889 
2020-04-09 14:07:00    95.469030  
2020-04-09 14:08:00    -5.434889 
2020-05-09 14:07:00    95.469030  
2020-05-09 14:08:00    -5.434889 
2020-06-09 14:07:00    95.469030  
2020-06-09 14:08:00    -5.434889 


sdf = 
                       dA
2020-04-09         0.993480 
2020-06-09         0.910515
```

I want to slice the rows of the mdf that matches the dates in the index of the sdf.

My code:

```
opdf = mdf.loc[sdf.index.tolist()]
```

Presently it is giving errors.

```
KeyError: "None of [DatetimeIndex(['2019-01-25', '2019-01-26', '2019-01-30', '2019-02-01',\n               '2019-02-02', '2019-02-03', '2019-02-04', '2019-02-05',\n               '2019-02-07', '2019-02-13',\n               ...\n               '2020-03-29', '2020-03-30', '2020-03-31', '2020-04-01',\n               '2020-04-02', '2020-04-03', '2020-04-04', '2020-04-05',\n               '2020-04-07', '2020-04-08'],\n              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='datetime', length=239, freq=None)] are in the [index]"
```

Comment: *Presently it is giving errors.* what error?

Comment: `mdf[mdf.index.normalize().isin(sdf.index)]` Seems pretty similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61412731/how-to-select-a-subset-of-pandas-datetimeindex-whose-data-are-in-a-list, which was asked like 2 hours ago.

Comment: @ALollz I tried this. Got the following error `TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: It would seem you accidentally used `[]` in your code instead of `()`. Are you sure it's `isin()`, with **parentheses**

Comment: You were right. I accidentally used [] isntead (). Now it is rectified. Thanks a ton.